# UIImageView Animation delay between frames?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, animation, uiimageview

I am trying to create an animation using a UIImageView with an array if images. It works great, except that I need a different delay between some of the frames. In an animated gif you can set the delay between frames. Every example I see of an animated UIImageView has a fixed delay between images.

Does anyone know how I can set a different delay between frames? Or, is there an example of such?

Maybe UIImageView is not the right thing to use, so if anyone has an alternative please let me know.

I have posted a similiar question in other forums and no one seems to be able to answer this.  It seems like it should bo doable, since .gif images have had this forever.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It may seem hacky, but:

From `UIImageView` documentation:

> ### animationImages
>
> An array of `UIImage` objects to use for an animation.
>
> ```
> @property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray *animationImages
> ```
>
> **Discussion**
>
> The array must contain `UIImage` objects. ***You may use the same
>   image object more than once in the array.*** Setting this property to
>   a value other than `nil` hides the image represented by the `image`
>   property. The value of this property is `nil` by default.

So you need to add your `UIImage` several times to the array for a delay.

Comment: I think this is the simplest solution. Just add the same image more than once to get the timings you want. This won't add too much overhead since you're just using multiple references to the same image.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use different UIImageView to get this working. Try this application page. Might be helpful for you. Link: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/how-to-use-uiview-animation-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

`UIImageView` does not support a different delay between different images. You will have to use multiple `UIImageView`s and manage the transition between them manually if you want to have different delays between frames.

Another approach would be to use a [`UIWebView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) which is sized exactly to fit a `.gif` image that has the delay settings you want.

Comment: LOL,funny how I would need to use a UIWebView.  In any case, a gif image does not really wotk well for me because i need to start and stop this based on a user interaction. Not a big deal I guess because I could swap the image from a static one to the animated one to give the effect of a start and stop.  But really, it seems silly that this cannot be done, as it has been done in gifs for awhile.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to try my animation library in your iOS app, it offers a complete solution to this problem. For example, you could take a look at the [APNG](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apng/id447928057?mt=8) app, it is a free app in the iTunes store that displays animated APNG files. This app was created using my AVAnimator library which contains APNG and GIF decoding support. The APNG format works just like a GIF in the sense that each frame can have a delay time, you would use existing software to create the APNG in this case. But, it is easier to just encode a new .mvid file (this is a custom video file format) from a series of PNG imags. To create a longer delay, you simply repeat frames that do not change in the input PNG image series. Either approach could be used to create an input movie that could display with a variable amount of time in between specific frames (the overall FPS would be the same, but specific frames can simply repeat so that they do not change for say N frames in a row). You can also implement specific user interactions like starting an animation, pausing on a specific frame, and then starting again from that same frame.