# IOS GIF cocoapod that allows variable durations and loop counts

Tags: ios, animation, cocoapods, gif

Im looking for a cocoapod that enables me to use an animation (gif file) that is upto 200 frames, in an efficient manner

Further it needs to be able to:

- start/stop animation
- set a duration that the animation should run for
- Set the number of iterations the animation should run for

So far I have tried [FLAnimatedImage](https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage) and [YLGIFImage](https://github.com/liyong03/YLGIFImage) , and neither appear to satisfy the above constraints while both are excellent for running through gifs in an efficient manner

Comment: What are your constraints? Why isn't FLAnimatedImage doing the trick?

Comment: Constraints are the bullet list in my question. The original FLAnimated did not satisfy my first and third constraint, however I managed to get around those (see below), while the second constraint was something I handled by altering the original gif speed to the time i wanted  by using a gif editor

Comment: I think you will find that most GIF packages available will crash your device when used with GIF that contain a large number of frames (like 200). Be sure you have actually tested this before you ship you app, because memory problems don't tend to show up until the code is on a client device, your dev devices do not reflect real world usage.

Comment: @MoDJ, thats a fantastic point - thanks for bringing it up

Comment: Very like this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17665088/763355

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use FLAnimatedImage to handle my requirements. See below

- start/stop animation: handled by implementing suggestions outlined in comments here: https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage/issues/52
- set a duration that the animation should run for: fixed by using an [online gif editor](http://ezgif.com/speed)
- Set the number of iterations the animation should run for : Handled by using https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage/pull/60