# Slow GIF animation rendering on safari in IOS(iPhone 5 and iPad mini) and nexus6

Tags: html, ios, iphone, ipad, gif

I have been working on survey based website. It is working fine in all web browser but when I open it in IOS(iPhone5 and iPad mini) and Nexus6.

Link http://52.66.29.203/

All GIF animation running very slow and site is performing very very slow.

Please suggest any Idea what should I do to perform well in mentioned devices.

Comment: You can find a high performance GIF decoder you can try here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17665088/763355

Comment: Thank you for suggesting the way